# Entity Framework 6 + Oracle "Where In" Clause

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, linq, oracle-manageddataaccess

Despite our best efforts we have been unable to get Entity Framework (6.1.3) + Oracle Managed Data Access (12.1.2400) to generate an 'IN' clause when using contains in a where statement.

For the following query:

```
var x = Tests
.Where(t => new[] { 1, 2, 3}.Contains(t.ServiceLegId));

var query = x.ToString();
```

Using MS SQL (SQL Server) we see the following generated:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[TestRunId] AS [TestRunId], 
[Extent1].[DidPass] AS [DidPass], 
[Extent1].[StartTime] AS [StartTime], 
[Extent1].[EndTime] AS [EndTime], 
[Extent1].[ResultData] AS [ResultData], 
[Extent1].[ServiceLegId] AS [ServiceLegId]
FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ServiceLegId] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Using Oracle we instead see:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."Id" AS "Id", 
"Extent1"."TestRunId" AS "TestRunId", 
"Extent1"."DidPass" AS "DidPass", 
"Extent1"."StartTime" AS "StartTime", 
"Extent1"."EndTime" AS "EndTime", 
"Extent1"."ResultData" AS "ResultData", 
"Extent1"."ServiceLegId" AS "ServiceLegId"
FROM "dbo"."Test" AS "Extent1"
WHERE ((1 = "Extent1"."ServiceLegId") OR (2 = "Extent1"."ServiceLegId") OR (3 = "Extent1"."ServiceLegId"))
```

This is a trivialized example of what we actually have to do. In the actual code base this list can get quite long so a series of 'OR' statements is resulting in very inefficient execution plans.

Has anyone encountered this scenario? I feel like we've tried everything...

Comment: Try using `Tests.Join(new[]{ 1, 2, 3}, t=>t.ServiceLegId, x=>x,(t,_)=>{})` and see what that query expands to.

Comment: @RePierre Thanks for the comment! We did try that as well... unfortunately that produces an inner join on a subquery that is composed of a select + union all for each element in the list. While that works out to be a little more efficient we end up with a stack overflow exception after a relatively small number of entries due to the sheer size of the query / operations involved.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I'm running into the same problem with Oracle.ManagedDataAcess 12.2.1100.

Comment: @thejman Sadly no. We ended up abandoning use of EF with Oracle in this case and used a hard-coded query instead. It's possible updates to the Oracle Managed Data Access code have already resolved this issue - we haven't bothered to verify ourselves. Good luck!

Comment: We are encountering the same issue with Oracle Managed Data Access 19.14.  We have a query taking 15 seconds that should be possible in a fraction of a second.